# Remove html entities from user input

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine I have a string

"The boy's "dog" is walking down the street"

I want remove any " or ' from the text how would i do so i cant exactly do

```html
$string = "The boy's "dog" is walking down the street";
$newString = str_replace(array(''','"'), '',$string);
```

so how would i go about removing the ' and " from the string

keep in mind this is not gonna be a set string it will come from a user input form so it could be typed like

```
the boy's "dog" is walking
```

but when submitted it will pop up with an error because the string cannot go into the database with ' or " in the text so they need to be removed

Comment: why to change user data? `addslashes()` and `stripslashes()` is useful

Comment: Don't bother with mysqli_real_escape_string. Instead, see prepared statements within PHP's mysqli and PDO APIs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` before inserting it into a database.

`mysqli_real_escape_string()` will escape characters `'` and `"` and insert the values in database.

Reference [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: did not know that function could strip those :)

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to read up on [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I came back to reference this question and was very disappointed to see the original answer tht worked for me has been changed

Comment: Joseph, the answer is still the same. It has not been changed.